# Employees with the lower salary than the average in their dept

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got two challenges on my college exam to do.
The first one is to *`Show data for employees (name, salary, and department) who are paid less than the average salary for their department.`*
I tried this:

```
SELECT ename, sal, deptno
FROM Emp
WHERE sal < (SELECT AVG(sal) FROM EMP)
GROUP BY deptno;
```

But i get the `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error.

The other one i didn't started but is quite the same, *`Show the data of employees (name, commission and department) who receive commission greater than the average commission in their department.`*

ps: I'm starting with SQL so the topic isn't very deep yet.

Comment: why do you even tag `jquery`? also, which RDBMS are you using? your tag said mysql, ms sql server and oracle

Comment: It is Oracle, @Kristian, as **ORA**-00979 error code suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function for this

```
SELECT ename, sal, deptno
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      AVG(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) AS AvgPerDept
    FROM Emp
) AS Emp
WHERE sal < AvgPerDept
```

Comment: This solution is a bit advanced for a new beginner of SQL, I feel so.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to the first one is not correct

The expression `SELECT AVG(sal) FROM EMP` will give the average salary of everyone, regardless which department they're in.

To get the average for each deparment, you will need to `GROUP BY dept_no`

```sql
SELECT Emp.* , dept_salary.average_sal
FROM Emp
INNER JOIN
-- join with an average salary for each department
(
    SELECT deptno, AVG(sal) as average_sal
    FROM Emp
    GROUP BY deptno
) dept_salary
ON Emp.deptno = dept_salary.deptno
WHERE Emp.dept_no = dept_salary.deptno AND Emp.sal < dept_salary.average_sal;
```